# How do I get rid of older Docker image layers and maintain only the final build layer?

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-image, docker-layer

Like, i am using dockerfile to build image from one baseimage i have.
Contents of Dockerfile are like:
step 1) FROM baseimage
step 2) RUN tdnf install curl

after running dockerfile, many layers have been created, so main concern is that i have to ignore/remove previous older layers from baseimage(step1) which are having some unwanted libs files, and they are getting included in my final layer. Can someone suggest what could be appropriate approach?

Comment: You normally don't need to do anything; the later layers only describe differences from the earlier ones, and you need all of the layers to create the complete image.  Often if you have build-only dependencies using a [multi-stage build](https://docs.docker.com/build/building/multi-stage/) will let you install those dependencies and build your application, then "start over" with a new `FROM` line; would this approach help your specific use case?